# Excel VBA - Getting values from dynamic array - does not show real number

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Here is some code which shows the problem I am having:

```
Sub main()
    Dim V() As Long, x As Integer, temp As Long

    x = 5

    ReDim V(1 To x)

    V(4) = 0.65
    temp = V(4)

    MsgBox (temp) ' Returns value of 1
End Sub
```

I would like the variable temp to take in value: 0.65, but it always shows a value of 1. I am not sure what I am missing. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared `Dim V() As Long`. This means it takes in only integers. Change it to `Double`.

Answer (score 0):

`temp` & `V` are Long *integers* so cannot represent floating point numbers like 0.65, simply change their type to `Double` which can.